# rails has_many association between 3 tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have 3 classes: User, Bicycle, Transaction.

A user can have many bicycles, and bicycle have only one user (owner).
The transaction have one bicycle, and one user (the buyer)...

In my user model I have these associations:

```
has_many :bicycles_owned, :class_name => "Bicycle", 
         :uniq => true, :foreign_key => "owner_id"

has_many :trans_bicycles_bought, :class_name => "Transaction",
         :foreign_key => "buyer_id"

has_many :bicycles_bought, :class_name=> "Bicycle", 
         :through => :trans_bicycles_bought,  :source => :bicycle

has_many :trans_bicycles_sold, :class_name => "Transaction", 
         :through => :bicycles_owned, :source => :transaction
```

Now I want the association `bicycles_sold`... I already tried a lot of things, but I can't get the right code.. the right arguments...

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
has_many :bicycles_sold, :class_name => "Bicycle",
          :finder_sql => 'SELECT b.* FROM bicycles AS b ' +
                         'JOIN users AS u ON u.id = b.owner_id ' +
                         'JOIN transactions AS t ON t.bicycle_id = b.id ' +
                         'WHERE u.id = #{id}'
```

Comment: Ei! Thanks for reply... This sql statment works well.. but it not nice and readable... There are no other option, with "through" and "source" attributes?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://geoff.evason.name/2010/04/23/nested-has_many-through-in-rails-or-how-to-do-a-3-table-join/) is an article you might be interested in.

> I’m not sure if Rails 3 supports nested has_many :through, but 2.3.5 does not. There is a (very old) ticket for Rails. There is also a nested has_many :through plugin that is has an experimental branch for 2.3.x. I don’t like using things that are ‘experimental’.